# Choice type in F#

Tags: f#

I'm getting some error with choice constructs, need help in fixing the code.

The error is

> The 'if' expression needs to have type 'Choice' to satisfy context type requirements. It currently has type 'bool'.

```
let safeDiv num den : Choice<string, bool> = 
    if den = 0. then
        Choice1Of2 = "divide by zero"
    else 
        Choice2Of2 = (num/den)


printfn "%s" (safeDiv 15. 3.).Choice1Of2
```

Comment: Don't just plunge in and try to write what "feels right". You don't even hit the correct syntax that way. Read some tutorials first. I recommend http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Choice` has `string` and `float`, not `string` and `bool`.

```
let safeDiv num den : Choice<string, float> =
```

`Choice1Of2` and `Choice2Of2` are constructors, so you should not use `=`. (Why do you use `=`? I cannot understand)

```
    if den = 0. then
        Choice1Of2 "divide by zero"
    else 
        Choice2Of2 (num / den)
```

Then, you should pattern-match to print the content of `Choice`.

```
match safeDiv 15. 3. with
    | Choice1Of2 msg -> printfn "%s" msg
    | Choice2Of2 x -> printfn "%f" x
```

[(live example)](https://ideone.com/cpMXNT)